# In a left join, select row with value A, if not select row with value B

Tags: sql, join, sqlite

This must be simple, but I think I'm lost. I have a table A:

```
name    id
Tom     1
Barbara 2
Gregory 3
```

...and table B:

```
id    nickname    preferred
1     Spiderman   0
1     Batman      1
2     Powerpuff   0
3     Donald Duck 0
3     Hulk        1
```

How do I query the table to get a nickname when it is preferred (1), or any other nickname if preferred is not available.

So the result for Tom would be "Batman", while the result for Barbara would be "Powerpuff".

Comment: result for Tom would be "Batman"? how u r planning to display it? what hv u tried?

Comment: Vikrant, I would use a join like this: select nickname from table A left join table B on A.id = B.id where A.name = "Tom";  --- but this will give me both "Spiderman" and "Batman"

Comment: Can a single person have more than one preferred nickname?  What about more than one other nickname?

Comment: Thanks John. Only one preferred, possible multiple non-preferred. In the latter case, I'd like to display all non-preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below Query:

Which 1. selects row with value A, otherwise, 2. select row with value B
using **LEFT JOIN**,

```
SELECT A.name, B.nickname
FROM A
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(preferred) AS preferred, id
        FROM B
        GROUP BY id
    )AS B1
ON A.id = B1.id
LEFT JOIN B ON B.preferred = B1.preferred AND B.id = B1.id
```

Comment: Best solution to the problem as I described it. Due to a discrepancy between my description and my actual problem I had to use Giorgi's solution, but your response still needs to be selected as "the one". Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Just an immediate solution:

```
select a.id, 
       b.nickname 
from a
join b on a.id = b.id and b.prefered = 1

union all

select a.id, 
       b.nickname 
from a
join b on a.id = b.id and b.prefered = 0
where a.id not in(
                    select a.id 
                    from a
                    join b on a.id = b.id and b.prefered = 1
                  )
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0b7db/1

Comment: I selected Vikrant's answer as the best for a generic problem like the one described, but actually for my specific scenario (whose details I did not go into in my original question) your response worked better as it did not rely on the "max" function. Thank you for the help -- and here's an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

If SQLite supported analytic functions then that would provide a fairly clean and convenient solution.  No such luck, though.  It does simplify the problem that you want either all the preferred nicknames for a given person (of which there will be at most one) or all the non-preferred ones.  It is then fairly straightforward to use an inline view to distinguish between those cases and apply a suitable filter:

```
SELECT p.name, pn.nickname
FROM
  person p
  JOIN (
      SELECT id, MAX(preferred) AS preferred
      FROM person_nickname
      GROUP BY id
    ) flag
    ON p.id = flag.id
  JOIN person_nickname pn
    ON pn.id = flag.id AND pn.preferred = flag.preferred
```

Comment: yes, it is also a wrking one, with explanation for `sqlite`

Comment: Thank you for the help -- another good answer, I'm upvoting it.